# How to migrate from REST to GDAA Api without losing files?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-drive-android-api

**UPDATE:**
The question below resulted from a bug in my code (scanning the wrong directory tree), rendering the question irrelevant (and exposing my stupidity in the process). Even if it deserves deletion, I decided to keep it, since the answer (Cheryl Simon's) is correct, valuable and substitutes GDAA's documentation.

**THE ORIGINAL QUESTION STARTS HERE:**
The app, I've been running for awhile under the DRIVE scope of the [REST Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) created numerous folders / files in Google Drive.

Now, when building a new version, I switched to the [GDAA Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) , but none of the files/folders can be found under the FILE scope of the GDAA. It has always been my understanding, that the FILE scope has access to the Drive objects created by the app. Needles to say I did not modify the SHA1 / PackageName combination in the Developer Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File scope access is based on the developer console project.  If the same developer console project is used for your app using the REST api and the GDAA app, then you should be able to access files from either.

Comment: Thanks, I will re-visit it to check for my bugs and will report back with the findings.